# Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range on swift 4

Tags: ios, swift

I have a issue on Thread 1 fatal error on my code. I try to create 2 pickers in one view controller. But the error keep coming. When I tried to run on my phone, everything is okay  till this page (picker cannot move). It shows an error on (return subject[row]) on 6 line from bottom)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMQFh.png)

Heres my code:

```
Import UIKit

class ThirdViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, 
UIPickerViewDataSource {



@IBOutlet weak var classPickerView: UIPickerView!
@IBOutlet weak var subjectPickerView: UIPickerView!
@IBOutlet weak var nextButton: UIButton!


let subclass = ["AA234", "ASA231", "AA9292", "AAA839", "AA5682", "AAA789"]
let subject = ["Introduction to Database","Introduction to Programming","Mathematics","Multimedia"]



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: Any) {

    let picker = UIImagePickerController()
    picker.delegate = (self as! UIImagePickerControllerDelegate & UINavigationControllerDelegate)

    //select row first
    let selectedRow1 = classPickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)
    let selectedRow2 = subjectPickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)


    let selectedClass = subclass [selectedRow1]
    let selectedSubClass = subject [selectedRow2]


    let messageToShow = "Class \(selectedClass) with the subject \(selectedSubClass)"

    // insert  messageToShow in message to appear what u selected
    let actionSheet = UIAlertController (title: "Please Confirm Before Scan", message: messageToShow, preferredStyle: .alert)
    let okAction = UIAlertAction (title: "Proceed to Scan", style: .default, handler: nil) //{action in
        //picker.sourceType = .camera})

    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction (title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
    actionSheet.addAction(okAction)
    actionSheet.addAction(cancelAction)

    present(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)



}

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 2
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
     if (pickerView.tag == 1) {
        return subject.count

    }
    else {
        return subclass.count
    }
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    if component == 0 {
        return subject[row]
    }
    else {
        return subclass[row]
    }
 }
```

}

Comment: Why do you have components as 2 when you have two picker views?

Comment: i wrongly put 2 in number of component. It shows 1 picker with column. my bad hehe

Answer (score 2):

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
     if (component == 0) {
        return subject.count
    }
    else {
        return subclass.count
    }
}
```

Change  numberOfRowsInComponent code as above